# Translation url is not working on top menu in odoo (openerp) website ?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I created some top menus on my custom module and it was working well.
Following was my code for creating menu.

```
<record id="cloud_menu" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Cloud</field>
        <field name="url">/#cloud</field>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu" />
        <field name="sequence" type="int">2</field>
</record>

<record id="software_menu" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Software</field>
        <field name="url">/#software</field>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu" />
        <field name="sequence" type="int">3</field>
</record>

....
```

But the problem was, when I selected an Arabic (or any language other than English) and choose any of my created top menu (only menus created from my module), then it loads the English website.

```
http://10.0.0.90:8069/#cloud
```

When I entered it manually  then it was working

```
http://10.0.0.90:8069/ar_SY/#cloud
```

So how can we achieve the translation url in top menu on my custom module.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, Make sure that Arabic Lang is installed, now for your custom menu you created using English add Arabic translation this will load your your custo menus in Arabic when you load website in Arabic url.

Bests